# std::make_shared number of parameters in the constructor

Tags: c++, stl, make-shared

In the absence of variadic templates (still!) in Visual Studio 2010/2011, a constructor that takes a lot of parameters can be problematic.  For example the following won't compile:

```
    MyMaterials.push_back(std::make_shared<Material>(MyFacade,
                                                     name,
                                                     ambient,
                                                     diffuse,
                                                     specular,
                                                     emissive,
                                                     opacity,
                                                     shininess,
                                                     shininessStrength,
                                                     reflectivity,
                                                     bumpScaling,
                                                     maps,
                                                     mapFlags));
```

, because it has 13 parameters and I think make_shared is limited from arg0 to arg9.  The obvious work-around is two part construction, but I was hoping to avoid this.  Is there any other possibility here, apart from use of *new* instead of make_shared?

Thanks.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use construct a class which will then be moved into the heap allocated value.

```
MyMaterials.push_back(std::make_shared<Material>(
    Material(MyFacade, name, ambient, diffuse, specular, 
             emissive, opacity, shininess, shininessStrength, 
             reflectivity, bumpScaling, maps, mapFlags)));
```

Comment: The good thing is that make_shared will also use optimized one-allocation routine when creating shared_ptr

Comment: Sorry - I don't see how this avoids copying from local stack (where Material() is being constructed) to the heap (where make_shared will actually place it).  In this case, how can the copy possibly be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

you can create a "input struct" with all the relevant members.
fill it with the correct values and call the constructor with that as his only param.

Comment: Also a good idea, but I want to avoid extraneous "random" structs for things like this :-).